# Property scrollbar-width not working in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the width of the scrollbar to 'thin' and 'none', neither of them are working. I have also tried using -webkit-
NOTE: I'VE SET THE OVERFLOW TO 'AUTO', IS IT THAT THE SCROLLBAR-WIDTH PROPERTY IS NOT WORKING?

The following is my HTML:

```
<div class="chat__chatting">
        <div class="chat__scrollable-chat">
          <div class="chat__chatting__header">
            <div class="chat__chatting__header--img">
              <img src="../../assets/person.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="chat__chatting__header--descr">
              <div class="chat__chatting__header--name">Alexender</div>
              <div class="chat__chatting__header--location">Birmingham, United Kingdom</div>
              <div class="chat__chatting__header--age">Age 24</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="chat__chatting__body">
            <div class="chat__chatting__body--rcv-msg">
              <div class="chat__chatting__body--rcv-msg--img">
                <img src="../../assets/person.png" />
              </div>
              <div class="chat__chatting__body--rcv-msg---text">How are you?</div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat__chatting__body--sent-msg">
              <div class="chat__chatting__body--sent-msg--img">
                <img src="../../assets/person.png" />
              </div>
              <div class="chat__chatting__body--sent-msg---text">I'm fine</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat__chatting__footer">
          <textarea rows="1" class="chat__chatting__footer--textfield"></textarea>
          <div class="chat__chatting__footer--send-btn">
            <img src="../../assets/send.svg" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And SCSS:

```
.chat{
&__scrollable-chat {
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    scrollbar-width: none;
  }
  &__chatting {
    border-radius: 4px;
    flex: 3;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex-grow: 3;
    &__header {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 2rem 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      &--img {
        width: 11rem;
        height: 11rem;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-right: 1.5rem;
        img {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          object-fit: cover;
        }
      }
      &--descr {
        padding-top: 1rem;
      }
      &--name {
        font-size: 2.2rem;
        color: $color-text;
        padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
      }
      &--location,
      &--age {
        color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        display: block;
      }
    }

    &__footer {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      padding: 1rem 3rem;
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      align-items: stretch;
      &--textfield {
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        resize: none;
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
        padding: 7px 1.4rem;
        color: $color-text;
        outline: none;
        width: 100%;
        scrollbar-width: none;
        border-radius: 15px;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-right: 1.2rem;
      }
      &--send-btn {
        width: 4rem;
        height: 4rem;
        img {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          object-fit: fit;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please come up with a possible solution.

Comment: You can set the scrollbar height: `.my-div::-webkit-scrollbar { height: 8px;}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `scrollbar-width` is too new for browser. Ref: [Can I use scrollbar-width?](https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollbar-width)

For other solution only for webkit browser (chrome, safari, and newer edge)

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

```html
<textarea>ABCDE<br>ABCDE<br>ABCDE<br>ABCDE<br>ABCDE<br>ABCDE</textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

From the URL below, you can see the "scrollbar-width" is quite unpopular among browsers so that might be the reason why it's not working =>

https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollbar-width

You can use WebKit like

1. You have an element with scroll functionality.
2. set "::-webkit-scrollbar" on the same scroll element =>

   .scroll-element::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 4px;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: gray;
   }

Keep in mind that this "background-color: gray" is for the scrollbar background and NOT for the actual scroller.

3. Let's make the actual scroller (the moving part) a different color, now use the "::webkit-scrollbar-thumb" =>

   .scroll-element::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background: #000;
   }

Answer (score 0):

I am enhancing the answer of @rangerz as below

1. ::-webkit-scrollbar — the entire scrollbar, including height and width

   ```
   ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
       width: 8px;
       height: 4px;
   }
   ```
2. ::-webkit-scrollbar-track — the track (progress bar) of the scrollbar, where there is a gray bar on top of a white bar.

   ```
   ul::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px black;
   }
   ```
3. ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb — the draggable scrolling handle, we could customize the colour according to our choice

   ```
   ul::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
     background-color: darkgrey;
     outline: 0px solid slategrey;
   }
   ```

If you want learn more about scrollbar selectors, here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)